# Importing bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less into scss mainfest file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass, less, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to organize my stylesheets like in [#268](http://railscasts.com/episodes/268-sass-basics) RailsCasts episode. My application.css.scss file looks like:

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less
 */

@import "varibles.css.scss";
@import "layout.css.scss";
```

But problem is styles, included via @import, appears before bootstrap styles, and I want to be vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put require_self after require bootstrap_and_overrides

```
*= require bootstrap_and_overrides
*= require_self
```